# Show AdMob only on specific screen

Tags: android, eclipse, libgdx, admob

I have a game on Libgdx and I have been trying to add AdMob banner to it.
I have 2 problems with it,

1) The banner takes like a minute to load and to be shown on the screen and it shouldn't

2) The banner is showing on every screen and I want it to show itself only on the Menu screen and not the Game Screen.

Here is the code I used:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication  {
AdView adView ;
@Override
protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
//  initialize(new GameMain(), config);
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    // Create the libgdx View
    View gameView = initializeForView(new GameMain(),config);

    layout.addView(gameView);
     adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-4647665408548722/8293730490");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    layout.addView(adView, adParams);
    // Hook it all up
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    setContentView(layout);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The banner really takes a few minutes to load, so you must to load the banner a little time before show it. About the second question, you should set false when you don't want to show the banner; and set true to show it when you want.

Comment: i tried to do a thread on the androidLauncer that will check true or false but its making the game really slow... isn't there another way to do that?

Comment: @user3419789 You can use a listener to set the visibility modes in each screen. That will be faster than using a boolean flag

Comment: How can i use a listener? can you give me a document about it or a code sample?

Comment: Please, take a look http://tseng-blog.nge-web.net/blog/2009/02/17/how-implement-your-own-listener-android-java/

Comment: i did as they said there but it doesn't make the ads to go away

Comment: Try to use this plugin https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples

Comment: Or you can follow this steps: http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/integrating-new-google-admob-banner-interstitial-ads/

Answer (score 0):

**Concerning your first issue**,

Loading an ad requires a network request which is quiet slow. You can try defining the ad in a chronological order, though I doubt this will provide a better experience:

```
 adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-4647665408548722/8293730490");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    // Hook it all up
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    layout.addView(adView, adParams);
```

**Concerning your second issue...**

There are multiple ways to solve that. The best solution is to use an interface that has the ability to show and hide ads.

Define an interface AdHandler.java in your game's core project:

```
public interface AdHandler {
   public void showAds(boolean show);
}
```

Then, implement the interface in your android project.

Just follow the [official libgdx guide](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx) on controlling admob ads.

Go to the topic:

" **Control**
This example will show you how to turn the AdMob View's visibility on and off from within your libgdx app. "
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx .

It has all you need.

Answer (score 0):

I read this and implemented it on the code but the ads aren't going away.
here is the android  launcher:

```
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
//  initialize(new GameMain(), config);
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    // Create the libgdx View
    View gameView = initializeForView(new GameMain(),config);

    layout.addView(gameView);
     adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-4647665408548722/8293730490");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
    layout.addView(adView, adParams);
    // Hook it all up
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
    setContentView(layout);

    }
private final int SHOW_ADS = 1;
private final int HIDE_ADS = 0;

protected Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch(msg.what) {
            case SHOW_ADS:
            {
                adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break;
            }
            case HIDE_ADS:
            {
                adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
};
@Override
public void showAds(boolean show) {
   handler.sendEmptyMessage(show ? SHOW_ADS : HIDE_ADS);
}}
```

and in the window i dont want the ads to show up i did this:

constructor:

```
     public Main(Game game,AdHandler a)
 {
     this.game = game;
     this.ad =a;
 }
```

and the call to the function:

```
ad.showAds(false);
```

what is wrong with the code?

edit: i checked and the showads function in the androidLauncher isn't even been called i cant find the reason

Answer (score 0):

I've found this solution. Please test this one:

Add this into LinearLayout

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adMob1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="{AdID}"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"/>
```

Then add this into OnCreate

```
AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adMob1);
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
```

If it works, you can add your specific code.

For more information https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals

Comment: This code is for xml i don't have any xml file in my game

Comment: You can create one and add to your game, can't you?

Comment: I haven't really learned how to implement it on libgdx i prefer a progmatically way to do this

Comment: So try to do this steps https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals